# Не работает директива v-on:click на компоненте

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

Написал свой компонент

```
  export default {
    name: 'TButton',
    render (h) {
      return h('button', { 'class': { btn: true } }, this.$slots.default)
    }
  }
```

Что я сделал не так, что директивы vue не работают

```
t-button.white(@click="alert()") Send // Template PUG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на англоязычном stackoverflow

```
Vue.component('sample', {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('button', {
      on: {
        click: this.$listeners.click
      }
    }, this.$slots.default)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    foo() {
      console.log('foo called')
    }
  }
})
```

Использование

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sample v-on:click="foo()">bar</sample>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В компоненте нужно на кнопку повесить событие и пробросить событие нажатия наверх в родительский компонент: `@click="$emit('click', $event)"`

Comment: Спасибо, но на en.stackoverflow дали более рациональное решение